# Flink CsvTableSource Streaming

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to stream a csv file and perform sql operations using flink. But the code i have written just reads once and stops. It does not stream. Thanks in advance,

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment(env);

CsvTableSource csvtable = CsvTableSource.builder()
    .path("D:/employee.csv")
    .ignoreFirstLine()
    .fieldDelimiter(",")
    .field("id", Types.INT())
    .field("name", Types.STRING())
    .field("designation", Types.STRING())
    .field("age", Types.INT())
    .field("location", Types.STRING())
    .build();

tableEnv.registerTableSource("employee", csvtable);

Table table = tableEnv.scan("employee").where("name='jay'").select("id,name,location");
//Table table1 = tableEnv.scan("employee").where("age > 23").select("id,name,age,location");

DataStream<Row> stream = tableEnv.toAppendStream(table, Row.class);

//DataStream<Row> stream1 = tableEnv.toAppendStream(table1, Row.class);

stream.print();
//stream1.print();

env.execute();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `CsvTableSource` is based on a `FileInputFormat` which reads and parses the referenced file line by line. The resulting rows are forwarded into the streaming query. So in `CsvTableSource` is streaming in the sense that rows are continuously read and forwarded. However, the `CsvTableSource` terminates at the end of the file. Hence, it emits a bounded stream.

I assume the behavior that you expect is that the `CsvTableSource` reads the file until its end and then waits for appending writes to the file.
However, this is not how the `CsvTableSource` works. You would need to implement a custom `TableSource` for that.

Comment: Thank you for the info @Fabian Hueske