# Reading csv file by Flink, scala, addSource and readCsvFile

Tags: scala, csv, apache-flink, complex-event-processing

I'd want to read csv file using by Flink, Scala-language and addSource- and readCsvFile-functions. I have not found any simple examples about that. I have only found: https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_scala/cep/LongRides.scala and this too complex for my purpose.

In definition: StreamExecutionEnvironment.addSource(sourceFunction) should i only use readCsvFile as sourceFunction ?

After reading i'd want to use CEP (Complex Event Processing).

Comment: Have you checked out the examples? https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/streaming/scala/examples

Comment: Yes, but i did not find combination addSource() with readCsvFile() .. or even readTextFile() and readFile(). It is possible ? because of: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/datastream_api.html

Answer (score 1):

readCsvFile() is only available as part of Flink's DataSet (batch) API, and cannot be used with the DataStream (streaming) API. Here's a pretty good [example of readCsvFile()](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/dataset_java/mail_count/MailCount.java#L50), though it's probably not relevant to what you're trying to do.

readTextFile() and readFile() are methods on StreamExecutionEnvironment, and do not implement the SourceFunction interface -- they are not meant to be used with addSource(), but rather instead of it. Here's an [example of using readTextFile()](https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training-exercises/blob/701d69d5d5007a0db2fa70b4f500357c4e74c110/src/main/java/com/dataartisans/flinktraining/exercises/datastream_java/windows/DrivingSessions.java#L59) to load a CSV using the DataStream API.

Another option is to use the Table API, and a [CsvTableSource](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/sourceSinks.html#csvtablesource). Here's [an example and some discussion of what it does and doesn't do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295749/flink-csvtablesource-streaming). If you go this route, you'll need to use StreamTableEnvironment.toAppendStream() to convert your table stream to a DataStream before using CEP.

Keep in mind that all of these approaches will simply read the file once and create a bounded stream from its contents. If you want a source that reads in an unbounded CSV stream, and waits for new rows to be appended, you'll need a different approach. You could use a custom source, or a socketTextStream, or something like Kafka.

Comment: My purpose is to read a bounded csv file once by Flink and make CEP-type analysis. In this sense CsvTableSource could be a good choice. Actually i would also be interested about iterative search -type analysis from many csv files in parallel. This may not be possible by pure CEP ?

Comment: About CsvTableSource, is it possible to determine "timestamp" column and set TimeCharacteristic.EvenTime for it and also set EventDelay and SpeedFactor ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CSV file with 3 fields - String,Long,Integer

then do below

```
val input=benv.readCsvFile[(String,Long,Integer)]("hdfs:///path/to/your_csv_file")
```

PS:-I am using flink shell that is why I have benv