# Read CSV File in Flink as DataStream

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Apache Flink, with version 1.32, I am trying to read a CSV File to Datastream

I was able to read as String,

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.io.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.createTypeInformation
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.FileProcessingMode
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.{DataStream, StreamExecutionEnvironment}


object AdvCsvRead {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // set up the execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val path = "src/main/resources/sales_orders.csv"
    val ds: DataStream[String] = env.readFile(new TextInputFormat(new Path(path)), path, FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_ONCE, 100)

    ds.print()
    env.execute("AdvCsvRead")
  }

  case class Sales (
                     var ID: Integer,
                     var Customer: String,
                     var Product: String,
                     var Date: String,
                     var Quantity: Integer,
                     var Rate: Double,
                     var Tags: String
                   )


}
```

Need an example on how to read it as CSV with Scala case class as Datastream, since documentation is limited, need your help!

Comment: Have you seen this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48835778/8084588 ?

Comment: Yes, I have seen and used it, its 3 yrs old ,now Dataset is removed and everything is Datastream in Flink, that's the reason, I have done the same using Flink sql client, so I am sure it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is complete working example = https://github.com/sandeep540/flink-scala3-csv

Answer (score 0):

Got few examples

Got one recipe - https://docs.immerok.cloud/docs/how-to-guides/development/continuously-reading-csv-files-with-apache-flink/

https://github.com/rxda/flink-scala3-demo/blob/main/src/main/scala/com/ververica/Example_00.scala

https://github.com/twalthr/flink-api-scala-3/blob/main/src/main/scala/Main.scala